# how many qualifiers Hbase can support in one cf

Tags: hbase

I know hbase has flexible number of qualifiers and as long as there aren't too many cfs, performance wise it should be ok.

but after some research, I can't seem to find any place where it says exactly how many qualifiers(cols) that hbase might be able to support.

e.g. can I have a row that has 10~100mi cols?

from what I know, hbase uses aggregated log data structure and therefore the same row+cf will be stored under the same Hfile. which in this case, storing millions of cols in on row won't be a good idea no?

and also hbase split the regions by rows not by cols. which means no matter how big the Hfile is, if it's just one row, then it can't be split?

anyone has any idea? I might not be the first one who thinks about this case right?

Comment: in my experience, column-wide table design in hbase is bad, unpredictable response time for gets and scans, better to have 1000rows that 1000 columns when possible

Comment: @AdamSkywalker yea that's what I was worrying about. however, do you happen to have any good ideas to tackle this problem? if I have lower cardinality(~10-100k) but large dimensions(10mi), what would be the best way to persist it? I was thinking about bare-metal files, like one file per row, in columnar storage like parquet or ORC, but I don't know if there is better solutions.

Comment: can you explain in more details what is the nature of the data? if cardinality is 100k different categories, what is 10M ?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, so row key is the user categories(user segments), like women, man, kids, pregnant blah.. and each category has millions of users, since we are running in adtech industry, we are dealing with lots of users. so userIds will be huge.

Comment: sounds like you need userId as key and whatever related to them as columns, using mapreduce to calculate aggregations

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, that's indeed a good idea and we are doing it this way. the only reason we are rethinking about this is the response latency, since mapred job is not instant, we need to get result under a pretty tight SLA.